# Storing numbers are text Excel 2007

Tags: excel

When numbers are stored as text in Excel you see this little guy https://i.stack.imgur.com/co3H0.jpg
in the upper-left hand corner.  when you click on it it gives you the option of converting the text representation of a number to a number upon which math can be done.  also, when stored as text numbers appear on the left side of the cell opposed to the right one.  I have an array of numbers which are stored as text, but they don't offer that little green thing to convert them to numbers.  It may sound trivial but I'm using the Vlookup function to reference a large column of numbers to a code name, but it's not being recognized.  And the only thing I can think of is that it's somehow being read differently (the codes are most defintely in the lookup table, and ctrl+f will find them).  I want to know if anyone has an idea about what's happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the array in one cell or is each element a cell in a range?

Answer (score 0):

The smart tag is a little finicky at times.  There's a couple of things you can do.

If you're using code, you can multiply the cells in the range by 1, this will convert them to a number.

Alternatively you can convert the number you're matching to a string and then vlookup.  Something similar to:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A1,"#"),B1:D10,2,false)
```

Note `TEXT(A1,"#")` would round to no decimal places, you may have to adjust the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The format of some of the cells in the lookup table maybe formatted as text. If there are a lot of them you can create a macro that corrects them. I had the same issue in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9007404/191931) although it was the opposite problem.

Another way to correct them would be to copy all the cells in the lookup table in that column and in an adjacent blank column edit>paste special>values>add which makes each of them numeric. Then copy them and paste those back over the originating cells.

Comment: I may have misunderstood whether you want text or numbers as your result, but @Jesse has a couple of good approaches as well

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick to convert all numbers formatted as text back to umber format is to copy the data into the "Notepad" application. Then select and copy the data from "Notepad back into your spread sheet and everything will be converted to number format.